# I am trying to find a spyware agent like "SpyAgent" to monitor users on a Linux system

Tags: linux, monitoring, safety

I am trying to see if I can find a user monitoring system for Linux. Technically I am looking for spyware that I can install on my system so when I let my little nephew use my laptop I know he isn't getting into trouble. I can find plenty for Windows but I can not seem to find any for Linux. I want to be able to get screen shots and get visited sites along with a keylogger.

I googled this but there was almost nothing about spyware except the question about Canonical spying on people using Ubuntu with the metrics they collect.

I am willing to look at something that has to be built from source if needed. I would prefer not to have to pay for anything either.

I am also very new with posting to Stack Exchange, please let me know if I need to change anything in my post before hitting the -1 rep, thanks.

Comment: It's possible there is software out there that does what you want, but in my experience Linux and spyware/keylogging usually don't mix well.

Comment: You might want to read [this question on the parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/2750). Basically, for kids below the school age, you should perhaps not allow internet access without an adult being present, or at least without restricting to a whitelist of allowed sites. After the kid enters school, it gets trickier: the schoolyard rumor network still works just as well as ever, and at certain age, knowledge of "forbidden" or "scary" topics can be a certain sort of "merit" in schoolyard social circles, so it gets spread around, possibly in a distorted form, no matter what.

Comment: they are already restricted... but i am wanting to be sure they dont try and get around the dns stuff that i setup... plus they are 14 so they are allowed to use a computer but i dont want them using my computer for something stupid... the thing is they already have been told i am watching them and know what they do on my computer. i am just trying to actually do that now. i dont want to be the guy who has "enabled" him to do something he was not supposed to.